# Trying to find a sci-fi series about a teenage boy genius that I read as a kid?

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I'm looking for a series from around the same era as the Hardy Boys (I'm guessing 1940s to 1960s), its about a teenage boy who is a science genius, and has access to a lab where he invents and builds all sorts of fabulous futuristic machines. If I remember right, there were quite a few books in the series, but I was only able to get my hands on one or two of them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This could be the Tom Swift Jr. series written by victor Appleton

visit https://www.tomswift.info/homepage/index.html

Comment: this is exactly the series I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: And before the Tom Swift Jr series (33 books), there was the Tom Swift Series (about 100 books published starting in 1910) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swift